# Cartier Divisor generated by Global Sections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be an integer curve of (arithmetic) genus $g=0$. (the arithmetic genus $g$ is defined by $g:= 1 -\chi_k(\mathcal{O}_X)$ where $\mathcal{O}_X$ is the structure sheaf of $X$ and $\chi_k(\mathcal{O}_X) := \sum _{i \ge 0} (-1)^i dim_k H^i(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ the Euler-Poincare characteristic of $\mathcal{O}_X$.

Let assump that there exist a $k$-valued point $a \in X(k)$. I wan't to show that the induced Cartier Divisor $\mathcal{O}_X(a)$ is globally generated, therefore for every $x \in X$ there exist a global section $s \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X(a)= H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(a)) $ such that the stalk $s_x$ at $x$ is not zero:

My attempts:

I firstly considered the exact sequence

$0 \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X(a) \to \mathcal{F} \to 0$

where $\mathcal{F}$ is cokernel of the sequence.

This provides a long exact sequence of $\mathcal{O}_X(X)=H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$-modules

$0 \to H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X)  \to H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(a)) \to H^0(X, \mathcal{F}) \to H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X) \to ...$

Because $g=0$ and $H^i(X, \mathcal{O}_X)=0$ for $i \ge 2$ we conclude $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X)=0$.

Futhermore I suppose that $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X) =k$ (why?)

So I can simplify my sequence to

$0 \to k \to H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(a)) \to \to H^0(X, \mathcal{F}) \to 0$

My goal will be to show that $1$ is mapped in the left module morphism to an invertible element in $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(a))$, but I don't know how to conclude it.

Comment: You have too many issues. If $X$ is not projective, it is affine and thus every quasi-coherent sheaf is globally generated. If it is projective and since it has a $k$-rational point, easy to check $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=k$. What exactly do you mean an invertible element in $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X(a))$? It is a vector space, not a ring. Also, I hope you have realized that $\mathcal{F}=k(a)=k$. Rest should be clear.

Comment: Do you assume that your curve is smooth? Otherwise a point $a$ might not be a Cartier divisor. For example, take $a$ to be a singular point of a nodal cubic.

Comment: @Mohan: Do you mean that it's clear by using surjectivity of $ H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(a)) \to H^0(X, \mathcal{F})= k(a)$ and the fact that $\mathcal{F}$ globally generated? So for every $x \in X$ there exist a $l \in k(a)$ such that $l_x \neq 0$ in $\mathcal{F}_x$ which provides a preimage $s \in H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(a))$ such that $s_x \neq 0$ in $\mathcal{O}_X(a))_x$ by commutativity of section-stalk diagram? Or do you mean it in other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you definitely need to assume that your curve is proper to make sense of $\chi_k(\mathcal O_X)$. If it is not, then $H^i(X,\mathcal O_X)$ is not finite dimensional over $k$, so $\chi_X(\mathcal O_X)$ is not well-defined. Actually, it is true that any proper curve is projective (Hartshorne, exercise III.5.8). Thus it is harmless to assume that $X$ is projective.

Let me now deal with your first question:

> **Proposition 1**: Let X be a proper integral scheme with a $k$-rational point $a\in X(k)$, then $H^0(X,\mathcal O_X)=k$.

**Proof**: Properness of $X$ over $k$ guarantees that $A:=H^0(X,\mathcal O_X)$ is a finite dimensional algebra over $k$. Any finite dimensional commutative algebra over $k$ is equal to a product of local finite dimensional $k$-algebras. In other words, $A=\prod_i A_i$ where each $A_i$ is a local finite dimensional $k$-algebra. Since $X$ is connected we conclude that $i=1$, otherwise we will have idempotents inside $H^0(X,\mathcal O_{X})=A$. Therefore, $A$ is actually a local finite dimensional  $k$-algebra. Reducedness of $X$ implies that $A$ should also be reduced. Any finite-dimensional reduced algebra over a field is a field $k'$ and an extension $k \subset k'$ should be finite. Observe that there is a natural morphism $f:X \to  \operatorname{Spec} H^0(X,\mathcal O_X)=\operatorname{Spec} k'.$ And a composition of $f$ with a section $a:\operatorname{Spec} k \to X$ defines a section $a':\operatorname{Spec} k \to \operatorname{Spec} k'$. Now it is easy to conclude that $k=k'$.

Finally, it is not true without any regularity hypothesis that $\mathcal O_X(a)$ is invertible for an arbitrary $a\in X(k)$. In order to have this property you need to assume that $a$ is a regular point of $X$. However, I will not assume this and will prove a little bit more general result. Namely, I am going to prove the following statement:

> **Propostion 2**: Let $X$ be an integral curve of arithmetic genus $0$ over a field $k$. Assume that $H^0(X,\mathcal O_X)=k$ and let $\mathcal L$ be an invertible sheaf with a non-zero section $s\in H^0(X,\mathcal L)$, then $\mathcal L$ is globally generated.

**Proof**: Choose any section $s\in H^0(X,\mathcal L)$ and let $D:=V(s)$ be a corresponding Cartier divisor. Basically by definition we have $\mathcal L=\mathcal O_X(D)$. Note that for any $x\notin D$ we know that $s|_{x}\neq 0$. Thus $s$ generates $\mathcal L$ outside of $D$.

Now let us show that for any $x\in D$ there is a section $t\in H^0(X, \mathcal L)$ such that $t|_{x}\neq 0$. Recall that we have a short exact sequence

$$
0 \to \mathcal O_X \to \mathcal O_X(D) \to \mathcal O_D \to 0    (*).
$$

Since $D$ is a zero-dimensional scheme over a field, we see that $\mathcal O_D$ is globally generated. In particular, there is a section $t'\in H^0(X, \mathcal O_D)$ such that $t'|_{x}\neq 0$. Hence, the only thing we are left to show is that the natural morphism
$$
\phi:H^0 (X, \mathcal O_X(D)) \to H^0(X, \mathcal O_D)
$$
is surjective. It suffices to show that $H^1(X, \mathcal O_X)=0$ (because of the long exact sequence associated to $(*)$). However, by the very definition of arithmetic genus we know that
$$
0=p_a(X)=1-\chi_X(\mathcal O_X)=1-H^0(X,\mathcal O_X)+H^1(X,\mathcal O_X)=H^1(X, \mathcal O_X).
$$

Therefore, the map $\phi$ is indeed surjective. Thus there is $t\in H^0(X,\mathcal O_X(D))$ such that $\phi(t)=t'$. Hence $t|_{x}=t'|_{x} \neq 0$. So, $\mathcal L = \mathcal O_X(D)$ is generated by global sections at $x$. Since $x$ was an arbitrary point of $D$, we conclude that $\mathcal L$ is generated by global sections at any point of $D$. As a result, it is globally generated.

Comment: The failure of Proposition 2 in the symplectic geometry setting is a major issue with extending much of the "minimal model program" to the symplectic setting (Ruan's program).  Specifically, for an elliptic differential operator between two smooth vector bundles on the 2-sphere, as arises from the $\overline{\partial}$-equation on a holomorphic vector bundle on $\mathbb{CP}^1$, even if the kernel of the differential operator surjects onto one fiber of the domain, this does not necessarily imply vanishing of the cokernel (vanishing of $H^1$, which then implies surjectivity for every fiber).